# PyQt5. Controlling GUI from separate thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

I want to produce simple GUI, a label and a push button. When I press the push button it should invoke a separate thread (the GUI unfreezes ). In the thread I have simple loop

```
for i in range(4):
    self.label.setText(str(i))
    time.sleep(1)
```

the loop must change the label text each second. So I expect to see the GUI how the label changes 0, 1, 2, 3 each second. This is my code:

```
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clicked_1)
    self.label.setText("Lubo1")

def clicked_1(self): 
    for i in range(4):
        self.label.setText(str(i))
        app.processEvents()

        print("Sleep!")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Weak up!")
x = threading.Thread(target=clicked_1, args=(1,))
x.start()
```

The code works exactly as I expect when I comment x = threading.Thread(target=clicked_1, args=(1,)) and uncomment app.processEvents().

However when app.processEvents() is commented and x = threading.Thread(target=clicked_1, args=(1,)) is uncommented the code gives an error:

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'label'

I don't want to use app.processEvents() since I know this is not the right way. The correct way is to use threading, but I don't know how to overcome the AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'label' error. Please help.

Best Regards, thank you in advance.

Lubomir Valkov

Comment: There are several problems here. What do you think that `args=(1,)` does?

Comment: If PyQt is anything like PySide (both Qt) then you should use Signals in your thread to let the main thread do the UI changes. Updating your UI from another thread is asking for trouble.

Comment: This question is almost, but not entirely, nothing to do with `qt` nor threads. Instead it is about calling a method of a class.

Comment: @quamrana, I think it has to do with qt and threads, but the example code is very poor. And he should not call from a thread objects of the GUI.

Comment: While I agree that your answer solves the problem that the OP has, it doesn't address the question and the observed symptoms.

Answer (score 2):

You should never do such a process, Qt does not support gui operations of any kind outside the main thread. Sooner or later, if you call your GUI out of your main thread your app will crash because it calls methods which are not thread-safe. You should always use signals and slots to communicate between threads and main gui.

```py
# your thread class
class ThreadClass(QtCore.QThread):

    any_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, time_to_wait,  parent=None):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.time_wait = time_to_wait

    def run(self):
        for val in range(self.time_wait):
            time.sleep(1) 
            self.any_signal.emit(val+1)
```

your GUI

```
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clicked_1)
    self.label.setText("Lubo1")

    def clicked_1(self):
       self.thread = ThreadClass(time_to_wait=4, parent=None)
       self.thread.any_signal.connect(self.update_label)
       self.thread.start()
    
   def update_label(self, value):
       self.label.setText(str(i))
```

As you can see you your button start a thread that emit a signal. Your gui captures this signal and do what ever it need to do in the main GUI, but your thread is never changing anything of the main thread

Comment: @L.Valkov if you have any question dont hesitate to ask. In any case never modify your GUI from a Thread

Comment: Thank you very much @Lucas M.Uriarte , I highly appreciate your help.. I accept your advice. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, in such a case I will appreciate if you accept this answer as valid answer. So that other people will trust this answer