Python + PyQt : Interrupting another Process
I have a PyQt5 based app which is running on Windows. I have a main GUI process from which I start another process which runs a worker function. I wish to raise a KeyboardInterrupt in the worker process from my main process. Is this possible? Please see the code snippet below to see what I am trying. This works when I replace the PyQt part with a simple console interface. I want to make it work with the GUI though. Ideally, every time I click the button, the worker thread will print the value of the counter.
Edit: It is important to note here that I must have a separate process and not a thread as the simple ctr in the try block will be replaced by a more complex bit of code which might block the Process for a longer period of time. Also, the try block is used as it can be interrupted by an exception. Hence the interest in rasing an exception in another process.
import multiprocessing as mp

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


def worker():
    ctr = 0
    for i in range(100):
        try:
            while True:
                ctr += 1
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print(ctr)

def on_button_clicked():
    #This raises a Keyorad Interrupt in the main process.
    #It should somehow raise it in the worker process
    raise KeyboardInterrupt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.freeze_support()
    proc = mp.Process(target=worker)
    proc.start()

    app = QApplication([])
    button = QPushButton('Click')

    button.clicked.connect(on_button_clicked)
    button.show()
    app.exec()


you should use QtThread class, better than multiprocessing module and send a signal to thread to stop. See some thread example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73772915/pyqt5-controlling-gui-from-separate-thread/73773611#73773611. Let me know if you need more help.

I forgot to mention in the original post that it has to be a separate process and not another thread.

As suggested by @RaJa,I have used Eventand the _thread module along with another thread to solve the problem. The below code should help anyone on the lookout for similar answers.
import multiprocessing as mp
import threading
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import _thread

def other_thread(e):    
    while True:
        e.wait()
        e.clear()
        _thread.interrupt_main()
    
def worker(e):
    input_thread = threading.Thread(target=other_thread, args=(e,))
    input_thread.start()
    ctr = 0
    for i in range(100):
        try:
            while True:
                ctr += 1
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print(ctr)            

def on_button_clicked(e):
    e.set()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.freeze_support()
    e = mp.Event()
    proc = mp.Process(target=worker, args=(e,))
    proc.start()

    app = QApplication([])
    button = QPushButton('Click')

    button.clicked.connect(lambda: on_button_clicked(e))
    button.show()
    app.exec()


Well, it's not what I had in mind :) But this nesting might be the only way to make sure that the keyboard-interrupt is handled in your worker. And if it works +1

To do that you first have to encapsulate your worker inside a class that derives from QThread, QProcess or the multiprocessing.Process/Thread. The class needs a public run-function that contains your actual work.
If you use QThread/QProcess than your class needs an additional public slot which is connected to a signal that is emitted when the Button in GUI is clicked.
If you use the Process/Thread from Python's native multiprocessing module then you don't need slots/signals and you can use a simple additional public function that is called when the Button is clicked.
In both ways it might get tricky, when your worker is way too busy to actual check its internal message queue. Even KeyboardInterupts are only processed if there is time for it (like a small break in a calculation).
So in pseudo code it would look like the following using Qt:
class worker(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # your init stuff here
    def run(self):
        # your calculation here with an interrupt "toggle variable"
    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def key_interrupt(self, value):
        print(value) # the pressed key
        # change your toogle variable here, when you want to stop your calc
 
class myApp(QApplication):
    key_press = Signal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        # your gui definition here
        my_worker = worker()
        button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
        self.key_press[str].connect(my_worker.key_interrupt)
        my_worker.run()

    def button_clicked(self):
        key_press.emit(key_char)

You might be able to directly connect the button.clicked-signal to the worker's key_interrupt-slot. But I'm not sure how to get the key-char transmitted that way.
You should also check the Qt-Documenction when you are not familiar with slots and signals: Docu

Please see my edit above. I have to retain the try structure due to the point you mention about the worker being too busy. The way I understand it, an exception a sure shot way to get the process' attention.

In my experience even exceptions are not a sure way to achieve that. Try a convolution filter on a big matrix in numpy and try to interrupt it with CRTL+C. It usually takes quite a bit of time until it stops as the process is busy doing calculations. Only when it jumps to the next line of code is a tiny window for handling the interrupt. I had the problem in another project where I had to implement a message loop manually to catch Stop-signals as even setting a variable from main or raising exceptions didn't work.

Alternatively, you could implement a multiprocessing Event and modify your while to to while event.is_set(). That usually works in most of the cases. You can set/clear the event from the main-process.

I have managed to solve it using Event and another thread. It works as I want. Please see my posted solution.
